# How close does a dwarf star have to be to remove the corona from its neighbour in an elliptic binary system?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, orbital-motion, binary-stars

It is possible for a larger (wider, but less massive) star to mutually orbit a heavy dwarf companion star in a binary system. If the dwarf star gets close enough it can attract the corona of the larger star, removing it.

How close do their orbits have to be for this?

I could calculate the distance at which a test particle falls towards to one or the other star, but this ignores the dynamics of the system. For the corona to be drawn away, the dwarf star has to be close enough *for long enough* that the matter can rise up and reach the critical distance.

[image]

If the orbital distance is stable, the dynamics don't matter. As long as they are close enough, the corona could be lifted up.

[image]

However if the orbit is like this, there will only be occasional closeness.

If I know the masses of the two stars, and there are no other large bodies so we have a stable two-body system, what parameters of the orbit are required for the corona to -- sometimes -- be lifted from one onto the other.

Comment: I suspect that tidal forces from the close encounters will impact the system, making the orbits unstable.